# Force orientation change in testcase with fragments

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-layout, junit, robotium

I have an Android test project in which I wish to programatically change the orientation.

My test:

```
public class MainActivityLandscapeTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
public MainActivityLandscapeTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

private MainActivity mActivity;
private Fragment mDetailFragment;
private Fragment mListFragment;
private Solo mSolo;
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mSolo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    mSolo.setActivityOrientation(Solo.LANDSCAPE);
    mActivity = getActivity();
    mListFragment = (Fragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
    mDetailFragment = (Fragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);     
}

public void testPreConditions() {
    assertTrue(mActivity != null);
    assertTrue(mSolo != null);
    assertTrue(mListFragment != null);
    assertTrue(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

/**
 * Only show detailFragment in landscape mode
 */
public void testOrientation() {
    assertTrue(mListFragment.isVisible());
    assertTrue(mDetailFragment.isVisible());
}
}
```

The layouts for the activity is in seperate folders, layout-port and layout-land

- layout-port

  - fragment_main.xml
- layout-land

  - fragment_main.xml

In landscape mode, the layout contains 2 fragments (Detail and list) while in portrait it contains 1(List only).

If the device/emulator is already in landscape mode before testing begins, this test passes. If in portrait, it fails with a NullPointerException on mListFragment and mDetailFragment.

Adding a delay (waitForIdleSync() and/or waitForActivity()) did NOT seem to solve my problem.

How do i force the orientation to landscape in my test, while still being able to find the fragments using findFragmentById()?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when using the standard android ways of finding a view/fragment there is no implicit wait involved so if when it looks that exact millisecond it does not exist you get a null value rather than the fragment you expect. This is why it is normally best to use robotiums methods of getting views as they have this waiting going on for you. The easiest way for you in this scenario is to add a command such as

```
solo.waitForFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
```

before your code to set the value. If you are doing this often it will probably make sense to make this a method as having to have two lines of code every time is bound to be forgotten at some point!

It is also worth noting that setting the orientation does not work properly on real devices!